How to pass Array of Integer into GraphQL query using GraphQL Variable?
I'm new to GRAPHQL, I need your help for making a query dynamically.
I'm able to achieve statically but I need the query dynamically.
So, Thanks in advance!!!
Here, I've put an image for Static and Dynamic query formation.
Here is the Static one
This is the example of static ids and working fine
In static example, I can get the correct data according to the id, which i have passed in array.
So, No issue in Static One.
Here is the Dynamic one
This is the example of Dynamic id which i passes using GraphQL Variable
The problem in Dynamic query, I get all the data, but I need the data which I passes as id.
So, Please help me on this.
I've tried both ways as above mentioned, but I'm getting all the data when i use Dynamic query.
I need the output same as static query.

Please paste your code instead of taking screen shots of it.

GraphQL variables can be used to filter queries by specific IDs that you provide.
Example
{
  "id": [207]
}

Result One Item

{
  "id": [206, 207, 208]
}

Result  Three Items

Demo Server
Save as server.js
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');

// Define your type definitions directly in the script
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    singles(where: FilterInput): [Single]
  }

  type Single {
    id: Int
    title: String
    duration: Int
  }

  input FilterInput {
    id: [Int]
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    singles: (parent, { where: { id } }) => {
      const allSingles = [
        { id: 206, title: "Sample Title 206", duration: 120 },
        { id: 207, title: "Sample Title 207", duration: 150 },
        { id: 208, title: "Sample Title 208", duration: 90 },
      ];
      return allSingles.filter(single => id && id.includes(single.id));
    },
  },
};

// Initialize the Apollo Server with typeDefs and resolvers directly
const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

// Start the server
server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`Server ready at ${url}`);
});

Install dependencies
npm install apollo-server graphql

Run server
node server.js


Call by Postman
POST http://localhost:4000/

Select GraphQL in Body
QUERY
query GetCourses($id: [Int]) {
  singles(where: {id: $id}) {
    __typename
    id
    title
    duration
  }
}

GRAPHQL VARIABLES
{
  "id": [207]
}

Result
{
    "data": {
        "singles": [
            {
                "__typename": "Single",
                "id": 207,
                "title": "Sample Title 207",
                "duration": 150
            }
        ]
    }
}


If you want to same result as static, use this variables
{
  "id": [206, 207, 208]
}



Hi @Bench Vue, Thank you for Answer. I've used the same query as you have mentioned here but I'm still getting all the data instead of  the specific one.

Can you try my server,js?

When I used your server.js it's working fine.

That means your server's issue. Can you share your server code?

you're right. actually, I'm mobile developer so. I just want this query work. that's it. Thank you for you time & efforts. I'll check with backend dev.

query GetCourses($id: [Int]) {
  singles(where: {id: $id}) {
    __typename
    id
    title
    duration
  }
}

You can see here that I'm getting all the data when I entered a specific id:

